# How to lookup buffer visiting file opened via TRAMP

Tags: tramp, files

#### Motivation / Background

- I use the `ffap` counterparts of common file- and directory-finding commands, i.e. `find-file-at-point`, `dired-at-point` et al. in place of `find-file`, `dired` et al., respectively.
- I want to set `ffap-file-finder` (the file-finding subroutine defaulting to `find-file` which `ffap` uses behind the scenes) to `counsel-find-file` from the [`counsel` package](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper).
- `counsel-find-file` returns a plain, non-TRAMP-qualified filename, in contrast with `find-file` et al. which return the buffer visiting the given file.
- I thus want to write a function suitable as a value for `ffap-file-finder` (i.e. one that returns a buffer object) using `counsel-find-file` (which returns a plain filename).

#### Observations

I have tried calling `find-buffer-visiting` on the filename returned by `counsel-find-file`, but this approach breaks down when the file in question has been opened with TRAMP `sudo` syntax. Using the file `/etc/pam.conf` with inode `123` and device number `456` on host `foo` as an example, I have made the following observations in such cases:

```el
;; This actually calls `(find-file "/sudo:root@foo:/etc/pam.conf")' internally
(counsel-find-file) ; => "/etc/pam.conf"

;; These follow the call to `counsel-find-file'
(get-buffer "pam.conf")                       ; => #<buffer pam.conf>
(get-file-buffer "pam.conf")                  ; => nil
(get-file-buffer "/etc/pam.conf")             ; => nil
(find-buffer-visiting "pam.conf")             ; => nil
(find-buffer-visiting "/etc/pam.conf")        ; => nil
(nthcdr 10 (file-attributes "/etc/pam.conf")) ; => (123 456)
```

Inside the buffer of the `sudo`-opened `"/etc/pam.conf"` file:

```el
buffer-file-name   ; => #("/sudo:root@foo:/etc/pam.conf" 6 10 (tramp-default t))
buffer-file-number ; => (123 (-1 . 1))
```

AFAICT, `(find-buffer-visiting "/etc/pam.conf")` fails when `"/etc/pam.conf"` has been opened via TRAMP because `find-buffer-visiting`:

- compares the given plain filename with the TRAMP-syntax values of `buffer-file-name` and `buffer-file-truename`; and
- compares both inode and device numbers to determine file equality, but TRAMP seems to modify the device number.

#### Questions

1. Is it necessary for TRAMP to change the `file-attribute-device-number` of visited files? If so, why?
2. How does TRAMP compare files for equality in such cases?
3. Given a plain, non-TRAMP-qualified filename, how do I lookup a TRAMP buffer visiting it?
4. How do I make `find-buffer-visiting` work with TRAMP buffers?

(These questions overlap, but I would like to cover all bases.)

#### Addendum

I realise that I can call `(get-buffer (counsel-find-file))` in my example, but I fear this is not a robust approach in the face of multiple buffers with uniquified names visiting the same file. I am also curious as to whether there is a more general and "correct" TRAMP solution to my questions.

Comment: Perhaps you should raise a bug report to get `counsel-find-file` to return more useful results?  Or, assuming it strips the tramp context on purpose, to implement an analog function which does not do that?

Comment: @phils I have already raised [such an issue](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1140) about `counsel-find-file` returning a filename instead of a buffer, but note that `counsel-find-file`: a) is not the main focus of my question; b) does not strip any Tramp context; and c) does not claim to be a drop-in `find-file` replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary of the [spawned `tramp-devel` thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tramp-devel/2017-10/msg00029.html):

> Is it necessary for TRAMP to change the `file-attribute-device-number` of visited files? If so, why?

Different Tramp methods are inherently treated as separate filesystems, so device numbers must differ across them. Virtual numbers are generated as required to ensure this.

> How does TRAMP compare files for equality in such cases?

It cannot currently and does not need to. This is theoretically implementable, but of little apparent merit.

> Given a plain, non-TRAMP-qualified filename, how do I lookup a TRAMP buffer visiting it?
>
> How do I make find-buffer-visiting work with TRAMP buffers?

To [quote Michael](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tramp-devel/2017-10/msg00030.html) directly:

> Look for `(concat "/sudo::" filename)` or alike.

Answer (score 1):

This are a lot of questions, not easy to answer. And they will need to discuss.

I fear that stackexchange is not the proper place for this. I recommend you to ask at the Tramp mailing list `<tramp-devel@gnu.org>`.

Comment: Thanks. Although I have read through the TRAMP manual in the past I admit I had forgotten about its mailing list. Do you think I should leave my question open for now?

Comment: Here is the relevant thread for posterity https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tramp-devel/2017-10/msg00029.html

Comment: Thanks, I've seen. Will answer next days (being a little bit overloaded just now). And yes, I believe you could leave your question open, if you plan to add a summary of the findings, later on.